# Invoiced API time milliseconds issue

Tags: invoices

I use invoiced API

https://invoiced.com/docs/guides/subscription-billing

and I got records like

```
"renewed_last": 1493732122,
"renews_next": 1496410522,
"start_date": 1493732122,
```

What those magic numbers mean? I thought this is milliseconds from 1970, but it's not true. They can render data properly on their site, but I can't get date for me app. How to get date from those magic numbers?

Comment: Why you can't use api library https://github.com/Invoiced/invoiced-java In the examples timestams converted to java.sql.TimeStamp class

Comment: I use this library. The issue is some fields like createdAt are timestamps, but those I need just integer numbers, how to convert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the api docs all dates are in unixtimestamp
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

It is timestamp in seconds from Jan 1 1970, Java calculates time in millisecond

So the solution is

```
new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000L);
```

Comment: Heh, I tried without L and got out of range :) Thanks. It works